# Error when implementing wso2 retail banking sample

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to implement [WSO2 retail banking sample](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DVS310/Retail+Banking+Sample) and I'm facing some issues with the given sample codes.

It shown some error in `AccountOpeningProcessArtifacts.wsdl` in the AccountOpeningProcess project. And it shows the error in validating `issueCardResponse` property from `xmlns:cs="http://sample.wso2.org` namespace.

```
 <wsdl:message name="CreateAccountResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="cs:issueCardResponse" name="parameters" />
 </wsdl:message>
```

[image: Err shown]

And also when we test the installed service through JMS using tryit utility in Application server, it gives following error.

```
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="messageContext error">
   <parsererror xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
      <h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3>
      <div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 201: EntityRef: expecting ';'
</div>
      <h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3>
   </parsererror>
</TryitProxyError>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Configure+with+ActiveMQ you will need to add hawtbuf-1.2.jar to your app server